# PHP Redirect location with htaccess

Tags: php, session, .htaccess, redirect

In one of the page I have is where administrators are allowed, however, I use if the session isn't set, the header will redirect them to index.php and that method works.

If I replace index.php with **home** which is for the htaccess which changes it to index.php but it gives an error in the browser

This works:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['MEMBER'])){ header("Location: index.php"); }
```

This does not work:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['MEMBER'])){ header("Location: home"); }
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
```

The error in Firefox:

> **The page isn't redirecting properly**
>
> **Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this
>   address in a way that will never
>   complete.**
>
> **This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
>   cookies.**

What's wrong with it? How do I get this method to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redirecting index.php to home in your php file, and home to index.php in .htaccess.  Firefox is telling you there is an infinite redirect loop.

Edit:
index.php and home are the same thing, so redirecting to either will result in an infinite loop.  You need to do something like this:

```
#.htaccess
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php        # public page
RewriteRule ^members$ members.php   # member only page
```

And then in index.php

```
# index.php
if(isset($_SESSION['MEMBER'])){
    header("Location: members");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: So I cannot use the 'home' in the php header?

Comment: You can, you just cannot redirect back to itself.

Comment: @Wayne: You can use `home` in the PHP header, but make sure to change the value of `$_SESSION['MEMBER']` to prevent an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Au Contraire.  Here is how you carry PHP sessions id's within an `.htaccess` redirect...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/  [QSA,L,E=REDIRECT_URL:$1]
```

Pay attention to the last bit... `[QSA,L,E=REDIRECT_URL:$1]`

Answer (score 0):

You've created an infinite loop.
When PHP executes the following code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['MEMBER'])){ header("Location: home"); }
```

It redirects the browser to `/home`.
But in `.htaccess` you rewrite the URL to `/index.php`. Which then again makes PHP to execute the above PHP code.